# Graph execution error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Пытаюсь обучить U-net в колабе но при обучении возникает ошибка(OOM так понимаю Out of memory?), код и текст ошибки прилагаю

```
def unet(num_classes = 2, input_shape= (512, 512, 1)):
    img_input = Input(input_shape)
    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    block_1_out = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(block_1_out)
    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    block_2_out = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(block_2_out)
    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    block_3_out = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(block_3_out)
    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    block_4_out = Activation('relu')(x)
    #x = MaxPooling2D()(block_4_out)
    # Block 5
    #x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    #x = Activation('relu')(x)
    #x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block5_conv2')(x)
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    #x = Activation('relu')(x)
    #x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='block5_conv3')(x)
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    #x = Activation('relu')(x)
    #Load pretrained weights.
    #for_pretrained_weight = MaxPooling2D()(x)
    #vgg16 = Model(img_input, for_pretrained_weight)
    #vgg16.load_weights('vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5', by_name=True)
    # UP 1
    #x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    #x = Activation('relu')(x)
    #x = concatenate([x, block_4_out])
    #x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    #x = Activation('relu')(x)
    #x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    #x = Activation('relu')(x)
    # UP 2
    x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name = 'Conv2DTranspose_UP2')(block_4_out)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = concatenate([x, block_3_out])
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    # UP 3
    x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name = 'Conv2DTranspose_UP3')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = concatenate([x, block_2_out])
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    # UP 4
    x = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name = 'Conv2DTranspose_UP4')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = concatenate([x, block_1_out])
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(num_classes, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
    model = Model(img_input, x)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.005),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

```
model = unet()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

Ошибка

```
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-323f72cb5e32> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model/batch_normalization_3/FusedBatchNormV3' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2828, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-121-323f72cb5e32>", line 1, in <module>
      model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 452, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/normalization/batch_normalization.py", line 767, in call
      outputs = self._fused_batch_norm(inputs, training=training)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/normalization/batch_normalization.py", line 624, in _fused_batch_norm
      training, train_op, _fused_batch_norm_inference)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py", line 106, in smart_cond
      pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/normalization/batch_normalization.py", line 599, in _fused_batch_norm_training
      exponential_avg_factor=exponential_avg_factor)
Node: 'model/batch_normalization_3/FusedBatchNormV3'
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,128,256,256] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node model/batch_normalization_3/FusedBatchNormV3}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_4952]
```

Comment: Ну да, судя по ошибке `Out of memory`. Что вы от нас хотите? )

Comment: Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает как её решить?

Comment: Ну попробуйте поменьше всего - слоёв, нейронов...